# What way there is to implement a new signing scheme in Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, signature, forks, ecdsa

I want to deploy a new signing scheme for the Ethereum transactions as an alternative to the currently implemented ECDSA. This will be for future research purposes on post-quantum signing schemes.
The alternative signing scheme exists as C code.

The first approach now was to replace ECDSA in one of the Ethereum client implementations like go-ethereum. Another idea was designing a smart contract containing the logic for the signing which will be executed every time a transaction is performed beforehand. 
As I understood, it is not (so easily) possible to execute external codes / programs in smart contracts. 
So the only way would be the protocol change with a later needed fork of it?

I hope there is a way, maybe you have another idea.

Comment: How do you intend to use the new scheme? Will it replace the existing ECDSA signing or both will be available? Probably the easiest way is to add a new opcode so it can be used from smart contracts.

Comment: I have to figure out how to exactly use that scheme. It depends on which way is feasible. So for the smart contract approach there would exist both schemes, since the protocol itself is not changed. I will take a look on adding a new opcode. Thanks!